# Python While continues to loop even if i insert the correct value

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

**I have this code:**

```
choose = ""
while choose != "x" or choose != "X" or choose != "o" or choose != "O":
    choose = input("X or O? -> ")
```

but it continues even if the user insert x, X, o or O.

I am new at coding, anyone have an idea to make it work?

Comment: change all `or` to `and` and it should work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

`while choose not in [ "x" , "X" , "o" ,"O"]:`

Any of 4 condition becoming true continues the loop. You can use 'and' insted of 'or'.

Instead, try using 'in', 'not in' keywords of Python.

Answer (score 0):

the logic combination is not what you want.
[enter image description here][1]
if you input `O` for choose, the condition `choose != "x"` is true, then while loops.

I guess what you want is:

```
    choose = ""
    while not(choose == "x" or choose == "X" or choose == "o" or choose == "O"):
        choose = input("X or O? -> ")
```

it works~/:D

Comment: by using `while not choose in "XxOo:"` may be better